# How to cancel the loading of an image using onAbort and onError in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

In that application, I want to abort image loading in the page and generate some error on loading on that, but here I had applied as well, but we are not able to prevent loading on the image, so how do I do that and prevent image loading and show the error using onAbort and onError?

```
export default function App() {
  const handleAbort = () => {
    alert("Image loading has been canceled.");
  };
  const onError = (e) => {
    console.log("Error loading image", e.target.src);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501369497246-426438abca8e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
        alt="img"
        onAbort={handleAbort}
        onError={onError}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But if you want to cancel image load. Then why are you even loading it. Provide a specific reason of doing so. If you are doing because of testing purposes, then you can go to network tab in browser's dev tools and set the "No trotlling" to "Offline"

Comment: Yes, because I want to set a condition for Api in specific condition. It should not be uploaded that's why I gave